# Duplicate rows while creating sequence of rows

Tags: r, date, duplicates

I am trying to creating sequence of rows like below:

```
time_index <-seq(from = as.POSIXct("2019-10-21 06:00:00",tz = "US/Eastern"), 
                 to = as.POSIXct("2019-12-31 00:00:00",tz = "US/Eastern"), by = "hour")

constraint_matrix<-data.frame(row.names = time_index)
```

But it is showing below error:

> ```
> Error in data.frame(row.names = row) : 
>    duplicate row.names: 2019-11-03 01:00:00
> ```

Comment: What programming language is that?

Comment: `row.names` is a special argument to `data.frame` for setting row.names: So you could do: `data.frame(rownames = time_index)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Use `> constraint_matrix<-data.frame(row.names = format(time_index, usetz = TRUE))` instead.

---

**Full Story:**

You might want to ask yourself why **that particular** date came up with an error saying it was a duplicate (Working with any date around that time of the year always gets my spidey senses tingling!)

Sure enough - in the US the clocks go back at 02:00 on 3rd November 2019... so 01:00 happens twice.

We can see this if we just look at a cut down version of your time_index:

```
> seq(from = as.POSIXct("2019-11-02 23:00:00",tz = "US/Eastern"), to = as.POSIXct("2019-11-03 02:00:00",tz = "US/Eastern"), by = "hour")
[1] "2019-11-02 23:00:00 EDT" "2019-11-03 00:00:00 EDT" "2019-11-03 01:00:00 EDT" "2019-11-03 01:00:00 EST" "2019-11-03 02:00:00 EST"
```

Notice how the timezone changes between the 3rd and 4th result, and they're both at time `01:00:00`

This causes a problem when you set `row.names = time_index` because `row.names` is looking for strings. R valiantly converts these to strings, but watch what happens when it uses a 'default' method:

```
> format(as.POSIXlt("2019-11-03 23:00:00",tz = "US/Eastern"))
[1] "2019-11-03 23:00:00"
```

We've now lost our timezone code, so now both `01:00:00` instances have exactly the same string, hence the duplicate error when trying to use these as row names!

Creating a field of `rownames` in the data frame certainly gets around the problem (kudos @sindri-baldur) but you might have a hidden problem waiting to bite you later, because you still have the duplicate value in your `rownames` field. Thing is, R understandably doesn't care about duplicate values in actual data as it does in `row.names` so it doesn't throw an error.

It depends on what you're doing with the data whether you care or not - it may be that it doesn't actually matter that the two rows have the same label in which case crack on, but it may be that some of your analysis now or in the future picks up wrong values or timelines look a bit weird around this time.

You can do as you wanted, and create proper `row.names`, but ask R to include the timezone in the way it formats the string using the `usetz` optional parameter like this:

```
> constraint_matrix<-data.frame(row.names = format(time_index, usetz = TRUE))
```

Comment: You're welcome Kalyan! If you found the explanation useful you can mark it up or mark it correct